# Can firebase "deploy access" be restricted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

We are bringing in a new developer for our Firebase web app project, who will start out by just learning the code in his local environment.

Since the new developer will be running **Firebase CLI** in the local env., is there a way to set up his initial role on the project such that he is *[not able]* to run `firebase deploy` commands?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I did find this doc from Google:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?_ga=2.49153190.-1888993.1468450573#curated_roles

It discusses deploy access in section: **App Engine Roles** .. not sure if that is for Firebase as well.

If so, are there any additional references for how to go about applying these kinds of roles to a Firebase project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who has the "editor" or "owner" role for a project will be able to deploy (and generally make any other changes to the project).  If you don't want an account to be able to deploy, don't give either of those roles.